# SDKManager Install - No ARM files

Tags: docker, cuda, pytorch, nvidia-jetson

The l4t-base:r32.2.1 base image (jetson) provided by NVIDIA does not have cuda binaries
Pytorch is looking for. I am unable to download source files from Jetpack 4.2.2 (specifically cuda-l4t-repo-10.x.x-arm64.deb) to include within docker build.

I am building a docker container for jetsons. I used the l4t image from NVIDIA, but it is missing some binaries pytorch is looking for (I understand you're supposed to mount some files for CUDA, but I don't want to). I therefore was going to install CUDA 10 directly into the container.

I am trying to download the source files for Jetpack 4.2.2. From what I have read, there should be a file, "cuda-repo-l4t-10-0-local-_arm64.deb". However, I only see
cuda-repo-cross-aarch64-10-0-local-10.0.326_1.0-1_all.deb and cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-0-local-10.0.326-410.108_1.0-1_amd64.deb.

I created an Ubuntu 18 container to run the SDK in. I run the below command and get the following files...
2019_06_23_2352-26660552-NVIDIA_Nomad_2019.2.19174.2352_Release_External-L4T.linux.deb,
libopencv-dev_3.3.1-2-gb3f86dcd5_amd64.deb,
Jetson_Linux_R32.2.1_aarch64.tbz2,
libopencv-python_3.3.1-2-gb3f86dcd5_amd64.deb
NVIDIA_VisionWorks_References.zip,
libopencv-samples_3.3.1-2-gb3f86dcd5_amd64.deb
NsightSystems-linux-public-2019.4.1.10-a76094a.deb
libopencv_3.3.1-2-gb3f86dcd5_amd64.deb
Tegra_Linux_Sample-Root-Filesystem_R32.2.1_aarch64.tbz2
libvisionworks-repo_1.6.0.500n_amd64.deb
cuda-repo-cross-aarch64-10-0-local-10.0.326_1.0-1_all.deb
libvisionworks-sfm-repo_0.90.4_amd64.deb
cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-0-local-10.0.326-410.108_1.0-1_amd64.deb
libvisionworks-tracking-repo_0.88.2_amd64.deb
devtools_docs.zip
sdkml3_jetpack_l4t_422_rev1_b30.json

```
sdkmanager --cli downloadonly --user $NV_USER \
--view live --host --logintype devzone --product Jetson --version 4.2 \
--targetos Linux --target $DEVICE_ID --flash all --license accept \
--downloadfolder /tmp/cuda_pkg
```

Desired results:

```
- download jetson jetpack ARM specific cuda packages during docker build
- all cuda binaries are available in container
```

instead of:

```
root@24081bcd996b:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64# ls
libcudadevrt.a  libcudart_static.a  stubs
```

should look more like:

```
libOpenCL.so            libcufft.so.10.0         libnppc.so             libnppif_static.a     libnpps.so.10.0.176
libOpenCL.so.1          libcufft.so.10.0.176     libnppc.so.10.0         libnppig.so           libnpps_static.a
libOpenCL.so.1.0        libcufft_static.a       libnppc.so.10.0.176     libnppig.so.10.0       libnvToolsExt.so
libOpenCL.so.1.0.0      libcufftw.so            libnppc_static.a       libnppig.so.10.0.176   libnvToolsExt.so.1
libaccinj64.so          libcufftw.so.10.0        libnppial.so           libnppig_static.a     libnvToolsExt.so.1.0.0
libaccinj64.so.10.0      libcufftw.so.10.0.176    libnppial.so.10.0       libnppim.so           libnvblas.so
libaccinj64.so.10.0.176  libcufftw_static.a      libnppial.so.10.0.176   libnppim.so.10.0       libnvblas.so.10.0
libcublas.so            libcuinj64.so           libnppial_static.a     libnppim.so.10.0.176   libnvblas.so.10.0.176
libcublas.so.10.0        libcuinj64.so.10.0       libnppicc.so           libnppim_static.a     libnvblas.so.10.0.480
libcublas.so.10.0.176    libcuinj64.so.10.0.176   libnppicc.so.10.0       libnppist.so          libnvgraph.so
libcublas.so.10.0.480    libculibos.a            libnppicc.so.10.0.176   libnppist.so.10.0      libnvgraph.so.10.0
libcublas_device.a      libcurand.so            libnppicc_static.a     libnppist.so.10.0.176  libnvgraph.so.10.0.176
libcublas_static.a      libcurand.so.10.0        libnppicom.so          libnppist_static.a    libnvgraph_static.a
libcudadevrt.a          libcurand.so.10.0.176    libnppicom.so.10.0      libnppisu.so          libnvrtc-builtins.so
libcudart.so            libcurand_static.a      libnppicom.so.10.0.176  libnppisu.so.10.0      libnvrtc-builtins.so.10.0
libcudart.so.10.0        libcusolver.so          libnppicom_static.a    libnppisu.so.10.0.176  libnvrtc-builtins.so.10.0.176
libcudart.so.10.0.176    libcusolver.so.10.0      libnppidei.so          libnppisu_static.a    libnvrtc.so
libcudart_static.a      libcusolver.so.10.0.176  libnppidei.so.10.0      libnppitc.so          libnvrtc.so.10.0
libcudnn.so             libcusolver_static.a    libnppidei.so.10.0.176  libnppitc.so.10.0      libnvrtc.so.10.0.176
libcudnn.so.7           libcusparse.so          libnppidei_static.a    libnppitc.so.10.0.176  stubs
libcudnn.so.7.6.3       libcusparse.so.10.0      libnppif.so            libnppitc_static.a
libcudnn_static.a       libcusparse.so.10.0.176  libnppif.so.10.0        libnpps.so
libcufft.so             libcusparse_static.a    libnppif.so.10.0.176    libnpps.so.10.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate the url in the `sdkml3_jetpack_l4t_422_rev1_b30.json` to download the debain files that you are looking for .

Hope this helps